# Hide elements that aren't needed or used by 99% of users until they are applicable?

Tags: search, best-practice

I'd like to hide some elements of a frequently used page to declutter the UI for over 99% of users:

In an online product I'm working on, there is a feature that is used 0.003% (49 times out of 123,900 sessions) of the time: a search bar for added notes. Most people just quickly scan with their eyes since there are usually very few notes.

By default we display 10 notes. You can change this to 25, 50, or 100. We also display a previous/next button for page jumping.

Would it be wise to hide these 3 features (search bar, previous/ next button, notes per page selector) until there are more than 10 notes? Currently, almost no one ever uses the search field for notes (0.003%), and the previous/next buttons are only applicable if there are more than 10 notes. There are rarely more than 10 notes, so these buttons just sit there disabled or unused.

Comment: Can you create an "Advanced options" button/view?

Answer (score 1):

## Before deciding

Why do you want to hide it? keep in mind a couple of things:

---

#### Empathize

As interesting it is to learn about this fact 49/123,900 it is more important to learn why is this behavior occurring - more like not occurring. It's very important to understand how your users are using your product as what do they need to achieve from it.

I think by now everyone would agree that Why's are qualitative questions, so i recommend that you interview, user-tests, observe or whatever method is important to understand those needs.

---

#### Know your priorities, is frequency all what matters?

Quantitative data could be very tricky, severity scale - from usability tests - teaches alot about prioritization.

Severity in usability tests take into consideration different factors, the top two that you will always find is Frequency/Impact.

You see frequency alone does not imply anything, i almost never open my Recycle Bin, throughout my thousands of hours i spend over this machine i have barely spent countable minutes on it, does it mean it can be removed? nah, all it takes is a small mistake and i will delete my most important document, the impact in this case beats all the couple of minutes/thousands of hours, because when i needed that feature, i needed it crucially

#### We're not removing it, What about hiding it

If we know for sure, that those features will be **predictable, easy to access and self-evident** for the user **when the user needs it**, then we have nailed it, we can hide it safely.

But it's still important to mention that satisfying those factors is not an easy job and would complicate things, as you would have to test it etc.. etc..

so again the question, why do you want to hide it? is there a good reason?